# What does the exclemetion mark after the function mean?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to understand some typescript code and was wondering what this ! means:

```
let display = new DisplayContext(document.getElementById('container')!);
```

I know that ! can mean not in conditional statements and it can be used to allow a function to be called immediately after being defined. But in both cases I've seen in in front what does it mean if it's after a function?

Comment: I swear I did not see that other question, thanks. What do I do in such a case just delete my question?

Comment: There's already a question for that as well: [How should duplicate questions be handled?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)  :) But no, keep it around, it's good for search